# Historical P/E ratios of small-cap vs. large-cap stocks?

Tags: stock-valuation, market-indexes, historical-data, price-earnings-ratio

According to the [Wall Street Journal Website](http://online.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3021-peyield.html), average trailing 12-month P/E ratios on the major large-cap indices are currently (late September, 2011) around 12-14, which is slightly cheap compared to the very long-term historical record and very cheap compared to recent history.

However, the Russell 2000's average P/E is about 40.  There seems to be tons of data on the typical historical P/E ratios for large cap indices, but not so much on small cap indices like the Russell 2000.

Is this huge difference in P/E between the large cap indices and the Russell 2000 historically typical – since small-caps are generally faster-growing companies – or is it unusual?

Answer (score 3):

There is most likely an error in the WSJ's data.  [Yahoo! Finance](http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=iwm&ql=1) reports the P/E on the Russell 2000 to be 15 as of 8/31/11 and S&P 500 P/E to be 13 (about the same as WSJ).

Good catch, though!  E-mail WSJ, perhaps they will be grateful.

Comment: I wouldn't trust Yahoo! more than Google, necessarily.  Rather than sourcing information from either intermediary, one could check [Russell Invesments, which manages the Russell 2000 index.](http://www.russell.com/Indexes/data/fact_sheets/us/Russell_2000_Index.asp)  Currently reads P/E of 16.69.  Of course, there are a handful of ["Russell 2000" indexes](http://www.russell.com/indexes/data/US_Equity/Russell_US_equity_indexes.asp) .. need to make sure one is looking at the right one.

Comment: Alsoo remember that by the time a number gets published -- including via a search/aggregator -- it will have changed. Take these as samples, not as absolutes. And of course "Past results are no guarantee of future performance."